# How to move up a bazaar repository one hierarchy level up?

Tags: version-control, repository, hierarchy, bazaar, repository-design

I have a project hierarchy like this, with a bazaar repository that has been created in `subFolder_1`.

```
 a_folder
   +-- subFolder_1
       +-- .bzr
       +-- ... (more content)
   +-- subFolder_2
```

I now would like to move the bazaar repository one level up, like if I had created it in `a_folder`.

The new structure should then look like this:

```
 a_folder
   +-- .bzr
   +-- subFolder_1
       +-- ... (more content)
   +-- subFolder_2
```

**I would like to keep the history** (commit logs and content of the commits). How should I proceed?

Comment: You want all the files that were in the root of the working tree to be in a subfolder called 'subFolder_1'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went the easy way: moved the .bzr directory one level up.
Next commit, everything was removed / added as every path was modified (different root hierarchy).
Aside from that, it seems to work. I didn't notice any side effect.

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup before trying the following:

```
cd subFolder_1

# tell bzr that all your files moved into a subFolder_1:
bzr mkdir subFolder_1
bzr mv <all the files in subFolder_1> subFolder_1

# move the .bzr dir to a_folder
mv .bzr ..

# move your files back to where they belong
mv subFolder_1/<all the files in subFolder_1> .
rmdir subFolder_1

# now everything should be as you want it
cd ..
bzr commit
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy content of **a_folder** (subFolder_1 and subFolder_2) inside **subFolder_1** except .bzr of course.
Add and commit.
Move with bzr **+-- ... (more content)** to newly created subFolder_1.
Then, rename with explorer your top old-folder **+-- subFolder_1** to  **a_folder**.
Then you can also push your project to nother name/branch.